# Generate temporary URIs

Tags: uri, rdf, semantic-web

I have an application that, for a specific resource at URI *`x`*, generates a system of URIs such as `x#a`, `x#b` and so on, and stores them in an RDF graph at any position in a triple, even as predicates.

This is fine but the issue arises when the resource that should be described in this way is provided "inline" i.e. without a URI. In RDF I have the option to use blank nodes, but there are two issues I have with them:

- Blank nodes are mostly regarded with existential meaning, i.e. they denote *some* node. The nodes produced by the application are not just *some* nodes – they are exactly the nodes produced from one specific resource that was given to them at one specific time. In contrast, a blank node can be "satisfied" by a concrete URI node with the same relations to other nodes, becoming redundant in presence of such a node.
- Blank nodes cannot be unfortunately used as predicates in RDF (or at least in some formatting schemes).

This means that I have to find a URI, but I am wondering what scheme to choose. So far I have considered these options:

- Generate a new UUID and use `urn:uuid:`. This is sufficient, but I would prefer something that expresses the temporary status of the URI better, so that it would be apparent it was generated for this one case only. In comparison, UUIDs can be used as stable identifiers for more permanent resources as well, and there is no inherent distinction.
- Use a proprietary URI, like `nodeID:` which is sometimes used for blank nodes, but is still a valid URI nonetheless. I would append a new UUID to that as well. This seems a bit better to me since it mimics blank nodes but without their different semantics, but I would still prefer something more standardized.
- Use `tag:` URIs. Tags have a time component to them, so the temporal notion is expressed sufficiently. However, I am not sure about the authority since whoever runs the application will in essence become the authority. Another option is to use my own domain and somehow "grant" the rights of minting tags to anyone running the application (or just to anyone in general). This way, I can express everything I need (the temporary notion of the resource, the uniqueness since I would also include a new UUID in the URI, and a description of the purpose and use of the tags on the website itself).

  This is in my opinion not a bad solution, but it somewhat limits the usage of the application, as once my control of the domain expires, users of the application will no longer have the rights to mint new tags under the original authority, and they will have to find a new one (unless I leave the authority blank; while it is not strictly stated by the specification, anything is technically valid since implementations must not reject non-conforming authorities). I am also concerned about the time component itself, as it might pose a security risk (although it can be less specific). I am also not overly accustomed to the concept of tags, so I am not sure if it isn't against their spirit.

I can provide all of these methods as options in the application, but I would like to know if there are perhaps better options.